# Raspberry Pi 3b+ WiFi hotspot with hostapd Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator

Tags: wifi, hotspot, hostapd, wpa-supplicant

I have this:

/etc/default/hostapd

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=HOTSPOT
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=asd
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

/etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface wlan0
    static ip_address=10.255.255.1/24

static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlan0
    dhcp-range=10.255.255.100,10.255.255.124,255.255.255.0,24h
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 10.255.255.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.5.255
```

and on first boot I get multiple issues but I am not sure what is the issue:

1. hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started

and because of that I think that I get this

2. Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.

This fixed the issues and I was able to see the wifi hotspot running.

I fix it unblocking the wifi adapter:
sudo rfkill unblock wifi

but I need it running from the first time and not having to do this. What is the issue and how do I solve it without running rfkill to unblock, I suspect the problem is either wpa_supplicant OR the fact that I was somehow turning off the interface in my setup. Also after  running rfkill list phy0 wireless LAN soft blocked: yes shows up, so how do I enable it?

Comment: Don't use deprecated `/etc/network/interfaces` on a RaspiOS if you don't know how it conflicts with `dhcpcd`.

Comment: Yes I saw it and deleted that, its now `source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d`

Comment: Can you help further? I am trying now `sudo apt purge rfkill` so we will see maybe that will help

Comment: If you choose to ignore the warning in the interfaces file expect problems. You will find dozens of similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

The problem I made was there because I was mounting and chroot-ing into the image using qemu, and changing the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file directly, and for some strange reason that file was not being read or whatever by system and rfkill blocked wlan0 because contry was not set. What I did is let the system update `wpa_supplicant.conf` file itself by copying it into boot partition as follows: `/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` so boot loader or whatever updated the file and solved the issue with rfkill, another issue was that the hotspot did not show up, so I added `country_code=US` to the hostapd.conf file as well.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `systemd-networkd` so I can only help with [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) and I haven't used EAP authentication so far in my home network. Have a look at the examples at the end of `/usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Purging rfkill is not the right solution. `rfkill unblock wlan` will persistent enable WiFi.