# How to create a wireless and own RPi WiFi network?

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

I know that you can create a WiFi access point with Raspberry Pi but being connected via ethernet to an existing network.
How can I create my own independent WiFi network fully generated by RPi?
if you would be so kind to give me step by step

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a guide:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117360/125514

I had all kinds of issues and everything is solved, NOTE: read my own answer if using newest raspbian and rpi3

Answer (score 1):

An access point, like a router, maintains a (W)LAN of it's own.  Also like a router, when the uplink goes down the LAN the AP provides remains active.  Point being, it doesn't have to have an uplink to start with if all you want to do is connect the devices that connect to it (or just connect another device to it without the internet).  If you have a phone with a hotspot, that's an access point, and it will work when the phone is offline.  This is exactly the same thing.

There are some good Q&A's here on the topic of APs and hotspots, most of them step-by-step self-answers by [Ingo](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/79866/ingo):

- [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way)
- [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge)
- [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-with-additional-wifi-dongle)